# Itext 7 and C# - Different font for special characters

Tags: c#, .net, itext, itext7

Currently I use Custom Font as a default font for all my reports. Lately I was asked to handle special characters in text from "Segoe UI Symbol" font (Custom font still must be default for text).

Let's say that this is my header input text, and [Symbol] is one of "Segoe UI Symbol" symbols:

**"This is my pdf [Symbol] report header [Symbol]"**

Result that I've got looks like this:

**"This is my pdf [X] report header [X]"**

[X] - indicates that character cannot be rendered.

When i switch font to "Segoe UI Symbol", special characters will display fine on pdf.

Is there any way to keep custom font for all text but use "Segoe UI Symbol" font for all special characters that cannot be rendered. Like a subsitution font (there was something like this in acrofields). Or is there any other possible solution? Text can contain none, one or multiple symbols.

Comment: Im not sure with that. Meaby its possible to catch exception, and switch font on that ?

Comment: Please attach your code